# with-meta vs ^{} - Clojure

Tags: clojure, metadata

I'm confused as to the differences between using `with-meta` and the `^` reader macro.

Attach metadata too `baz` `symbol` using the reader macro

```
user=> (def ^{:foo "bar"} baz {:my "value"})
#'user/baz
```

pull it out

```
user=> (meta #'baz)
{:foo "bar", :ns #<Namespace user>, :name baz, :line 1, :file "NO_SOURCE_PATH"}
```

attach using `with-meta`

```
user=> (def (with-meta 'baz2 {:foo "bar"}) {:my "value"})
CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: First argument to def must be a Symbol, compiling:(NO_SOURCE_PATH:1)
```

however ...

```
user=> (class (with-meta 'baz2 {:foo "bar"}))
clojure.lang.Symbol
```

I can attach it to the value

```
user=> (def baz2 (with-meta {:my "value"} {:foo "bar"})
#'user/baz2
```

but it's not the same

```
user=> (meta baz2)
{:foo "bar"}

user=> (meta #'baz2)
{:ns #<Namespace user>, :name baz2, :line 1, :file "NO_SOURCE_PATH"}
```

can someone explain this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`def` is a [special form](http://clojure.org/special_forms).  Even though `with-meta` returns a symbol, the Clojure compiler doesn't (can't) know that. It sees a function.

```
user=> (def (symbol blah) "blah")
CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: First argument to def must be a Symbol, compiling:(NO_SOURCE_PATH:1)
```